# Inheritance: object creation

Tags: java, inheritance, instantiation, instance-variables

Let's say I have this piece of code:

```
class Animal {
    int legs = 4;
    int head = 1;
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public static void main (String []args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
    }
}
```

I am aware of the `super()` implicitly placed in the first line of the no-args constructor, so I know that the `Animal` constructor will be executed and so the `Animal`'s instance variable will be set.

To this purpose I would like to understand if, once those variables have been initialized by the super constructor (`Animal`), those instance variable will be kept there in the Animal object or copied to the subclass (`Dog`).

In the first case an object `Animal` will be instantiated implicitly by `super();` and whenever the instance `Dog` will need to access one of those variable it will be done accessing to the variables kept in the instance `Animal` (created on background). Or second case, if the object Animal will be temporary created, all the instance variable (in `Animal`) copied to the `Dog` instance and then deleting the `Animal`'s instance temporary created.

I personally think that for example a `Dog` object would be directly linked to an `Animal` object which is directly connected to an object.

Is it in this way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's only *one object*, which is immediately (right from the start) a `Dog` instance. It has all the fields of `Dog` (not that you have any here) *and* all the fields of `Animal`.

Initially all the variables will be set to their default values (0, null etc). Then when you get to each class's constructor body (after calling the superclass constructor), the instance variable initializers are executed, then the constructor body for that class is executed.

There's no copying required, as there's only ever one object. So for example, if you were to write an `Animal` constructor like this:

```
public Animal() {
    System.out.println(this.getClass());
}
```

... it would print out `Dog`, because the object is already a `Dog`, even though its `Dog` constructor won't have been executed yet.

Comment: @zvzdhk Because the object itself is a `Dog`. Even in the constructor (and also in the `super` constructor) `this` refers to the current object. So it may look strange, but it`s quite straightforward.

Comment: @GaborSch: I *think* zvzdhk might have been referring to the speed of response, rather than asking a technical question. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: @GaborSch, no, answer is clear. I opened this question exactly as it had been published. And when I finished to read question, Jon already posted this answer...

Comment: OK, guys, then please @JonSkeet answer *me*: how do you do that? I catched this post when it was *37 seconds* old, but took me more than 5 minutes to type my answer.

Comment: @GaborSch: Practice, I guess. I'm a reasonably quick typist, and I have a fair amount of experience at explaining this sort of thing.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good for you, I feel I have no chance to give a valuable answer if you are online (unfortunately we're in the same time zone). I hope you are sleeping sometimes :D

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you know also how an Object instance is physically connected to the superClass,say, public variable? What physically actually happens when we use the keyword extends. how that bridge get created? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Rollerball  Actually one object is allocated, with all the properties of the super class and the sub class. It is a continuous memory area, the super members are at the beginning, the sub members are at the end of the memory area. Then those members are initialized (e.g. `head=1`), then the constructors are called. Remember, the should must call `super()` as the first call, so it starts with `Object()` then `Animal()` finally with`Dog()`.

Comment: @GaborSch ok but how those super properties get physically retrieved? what kind of magic connection does the keyword "extends" do?

Comment: No magic, I'll try to explain in my answer (need some drawing).

Comment: @Rollerball: It's not really clear what level you you're trying to find out about. Each object contains a reference to its actual type, which is how it "knows" what to do. In terms of how everything's executed, it gets very complicated due to JIT compilation etc. If you're relatively new to Java, it's worth just working out *what* is going to happen (according to the language specification) without worrying too much about the implementation.

Answer (score 9):

Your `Dog` extends `Animal`, and the `head`, `legs` variables are not private, so you will access them from the `Dog` instance.

In practice, the following happens:

- You create a `Dog` instance, which is also an `Animal`
- all the object properties are created and initialized (including `head`, and after the properties of `Animal` as well)
- The implicit constructor of `Dog` is called (it calls `super()`)
- The implicit constructor of `Animal` is called

And the result is an Object, which is a `Dog`, but implicitly also an `Animal`.

---

How a `Dog` object looks like (let's forget about the `Object` class for the sake of the example). Let's suppose `Dog` has a `public String name;` property as well.

Here is a memory map of a Dog instance:

```
Addr  Type     Name      Defined in:
------------------------
| 0 | int    | legs    | Animal
| 1 | int    | head    | Animal
| 2 | String | name    | Dog
------------------------
```

- If you have an `Animal`, you access the `head` as a variable at **address 1**,
- If you have a `Dog`, you access the `name` as a variable at **address 2**,
- If you have an `Dog`, you access the `head` as a variable at **address 1**

The code that runs in the body of `Animal` class can see only addresses `0-1`. The code that runs in the `Dog` class can access addresses `0-2`. If a property would be `private` to the superclass, then that address would be forbidden for the subclass.

This memory map makes is possible to downcast the objects very easily: the same memory mapping is used, only the treatment (the code and the visibility) is different.

I hope it clarifies a bit.

Comment: Updated with the explanation of the inherited object structure.

Answer (score 2):

> once those variables have been initialized by the super constructor
>   (Animal), those instance variable will be kept there in the Animal
>   object or copied to the subclass (Dog).

Firstly, Instance variables are **not overriden** in `sub-class`. they are only **visible**. They will not be copied in Dog's instance. You can access them from Dog class with Dog's instance if they are marked either public, protected or no-modifier

Comment: So are linked together as I thought? How many objects created eventually?

Comment: @Rollerball as John skeet already answered it, there will only be one object created(Dog object) :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no Animal Object , only a Dog object will be created . The Dog object has variables legs,head inherited from Animal object. They will act as if its the members of Dog object. Animal class constructor will be called since you are extending the Animal class in Dog.And since Animal implicitly extends Object , the Object class constructor will be called from Animal.

How Java handles these calls are internal to Java and may change from version to version but behavior you should expect to keep same.